How to Dynamically Create Class Methods in Python Using Decorators?
I am working on a Python project where I need to dynamically create methods for a class at runtime. I want to use a decorator to add these methods to the class, based on some external configuration. The requirements are:
The decorator should read method definitions from an external configuration (e.g., a dictionary).
The decorator should dynamically add these methods to the class.
Each generated method should have its own unique implementation as specified in the configuration.
Here is a rough outline of what I am imaging:
method_config = {
    'method1': lambda self: "This is method1",
    'method2': lambda self, arg: f"Method2 received {arg}"
}

@dynamic_methods(method_config)
class MyClass:
    ...


Security risks
Since the decorator iterates through method_config, if this configuration comes from an untrusted source, it could introduce vulnerabilities (code injection, resource exhaustion, overwriting existing methods).
Solution
Python classes use a dictionary-like mechanism, we can leverage setattr.
def dynamic_methods(method_config):
    def decorator(cls):
        for method_name, method_impl in method_config.items():
            setattr(cls, method_name, method_impl)
        return cls
    return decorator

method_config = {
    'method1': lambda self: "This is method1",
    'method2': lambda self, arg: f"Method2 received {arg}"
}

@dynamic_methods(method_config)
class MyClass:
    pass

# Usage
obj = MyClass()
print(obj.method1())  # Output: This is method1
print(obj.method2("test"))  # Output: Method2 received test

